# New features in MVC 6 Can be run other hosts then IIS?

Tags: apache, iis, cross-platform, asp.net-core-mvc

I came to know that MVC6 will support cross platform.
Is there any other option to host **.net Core MVC6** *other than* IIS to make it cross platform supporte?
** Can we deploy MVC6 app in Tomcat Apache server?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot deploy ASP.NET Core to a Tomcat server, as the Tomcat is a JAVA servlet container.

**But:**

of course you can use any other Platform than IIS. Just use Kestrel, that means, go to your Linux shell, get your code and do

```
dotnet restore && dotnet run
```

in the ASP.NET Core MVC application folder.
You will find the kestrel webserver running at port 5000. To use Apache as a frontend, configure your apache to use HTTP and/or HTTPS at ports 80 and 443, then add

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
```

to your VirtualHost configuration and enable mod_proxy and mod_proxy_http in apache2:

```
a2enmod proxy proxy_http
```

You can then filter port 5000 for connections other than localhost (e.g. with iptables).

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i need MVC 6 Can be hosts other then IIS?   server that support all other languages

Comment: as far as I'm aware, MVC6 has been renamed MVC Core. If you need ASP.NET MVC using the .NET Framework (**not** .NET Core), then you're stuck with IIS. If you're concerned about security you can put e.g. Apache as Front-End server using ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse as mentioned above with ProxyPass http://my.iis.server/ and ProxyPassreverse respectively.
Also see: [link](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNET5IsDeadIntroducingASPNETCore10AndNETCore10.aspx), If you are on the .NET Core side, everything is possible. If you are on the .NET Framework side, Win/IIS is the way to go.